# undefined method `sub_categories' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a category system for my blog but I've hit this error. Each `blog_category` can have multiple `sub_categories` by having `parent_id` pointing to the id of the main category. Some `sub_categories` and main `blog_categories` don't have anything in them. How would I prevent this `NoMethodError` from hitting?

BlogCategoriesController:

```
class BlogCategoriesController < ApplicationController

def index
  @category = BlogCategory.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @sub_category = @category.sub_categories.first
  @posts = @subcategory.posts
end

private

  def cat_params
    params.require(:blog_category).permit(:name, :parent_id, :sub_category)
  end

end
```

BlogCategory Model:

```
class BlogCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts

  # This is called a self referential relation. This is where records in a table may point to other records in the same table.
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: "BlogCategory", foreign_key: :parent_id

  # This is a scope to load the top level categories and eager-load their posts, subcategories, and the subcategories' posts too.
  scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :posts, sub_categories: :posts }
end
```

The Posts point to the blog category via `t.integer "blog_category_id"` in the post table and has a `belongs_to :blog_category` in the Post model.

Comment: What code are you executing that leads to the error? Can you show a stack trace?

Comment: Assuming that the error occurs in your `index` action here: `@sub_category = @category.sub_categories.first`, then your error has nothing to do with your associations. Instead, apparently, `BlogCategory.find_by_id(params[:id])` has returned `nil` which, as stated in the error, does not respond to `sub_categories`.

Comment: `@category` can be `nil` because of `find_by` - use `find` and in this case rails will raise a `404 Not found` automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a validation

```
def index
  @category = BlogCategory.find_by_id(params[:id])
  unless @category.nil?
      @sub_category = @category.sub_categories.first
      @posts = @subcategory.posts
  end
end
```